# Обновление Linux

Tags: установка, linux

Задавала по Линуксу три вопроса. Муж уже все это (то, что советовали) сделал. Но все равно не можем обновить браузер (у нас по умолчанию Мозилла 2.0) и флешплеер( 9 версия). Со старыми версиями уже в "Одноклассниках" не могу ни читать ничего, ни сообщения писать. Система пишет, чтобы обновили все ( см. выше), так как версии старые. Нетбук выпуска 2009 года. Все остальные функции (кроме интернета) работают просто замечательно. Может быть у нас урезанная версия Линукс-Дебиан, потому и сделать ничего нельзя??? Пробовали устанавливать с флешки Линукс-Слакс. Все получилось, кроме соединения с модемом. Проделывали все операции, что подсказывали знакомые, ничего не выходит. На модеме ломпочка Линк горит, а Эзернет (то есть, соединение нетбука и модема) нет.

Comment: Расскажите по шагам, как вы пытаетесь обновить браузер и флешплеер?Заодно хотелось бы узнать версию ОС и модель нетбука. Ну и почему пытаетесь установить именно линукс? Может быть в windows вам было бы проще?

Comment: Линукс Дебиан GNU/Linux 4.0\n\l. Это про систему. Модель нетбука Eee PC. А Линукс мы не пытаеися установить, он стоит по умолчанию изначально. Пытались установить флешплеер, но в этой версии Линукса отсутствуют пакеты rpm. Видимо, из-за этого не возможно обновить всё. Если сможете, то подскажите, где они могут храниться?

Comment: немного не в тему,но Chrome на офф.сайте можно скачать,в один клик

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно верно, Демьян - это *.deb-пакеты. Есть, конечно, возможность "переконвертировать" пакеты, но, ИМХО, не для Вашего случая. Распространенные пакеты есть во всех вариантах.

Необходимо пользоваться пакетным менеджером apt-get  или aptitude. Зайдите сюда: [пакетный менеджер APT](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apt) или [управление пакетами](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.ru.html).

Как понял из этой фразы: "Непосредственные обновления с выпусков Debian старее 5.0 (lenny) не поддерживаются." Т.е. обновиться через apt до новой версии системы не выйдет.Вывод: или скачать пакеты и установить их с Вашего компа (но тут могут всплыть зависимости), или необходимо скачать свежий дистрибутив и обновляться с загрузочного CD/DVD.

Comment: Спасибо. Будем пробовать. Вчера вечером муж до чего-то добравлся. Правда, не знаю, до чего именно. Ему приходится осваивать Линукс, так как работает-то он на ХР. Так что благодарим за советы.

Comment: Вся особенность Linux по сравнению с WXP состоит в том, что следует вдумчиво читать инструкции. В свое время находился в такой же ситуации.   Так что удачи Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Debian понимает пакеты *.deb, RPM вы на него не поставите, может, в этом и проблема?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вчера муж, как-то, "дошел" до этого сам. Значит, в правильном направлении движемся.

Answer (score 0):

> а Эзернет (то есть, соединение нетбукаи модема) нет.

Проверяйте кабель от компа до модема

Answer (score 0):

Нужно удалить старую версию и добавить репозитории для новых версий

Ещо совет, если хотите использовать новый дистрибутив, лучше снесите и поставьте с нуля - лучше будет!! У меня щас Ubuntu 11.10 стабильно работает, вроде даже можно сравнить с 10.04!!

Вот [инструкция](http://ubuntunews.ru/apps/firefox-and-thunderbird-5-6-7-8.html).

> `Firefox`
>
> `5.0 (Stable):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stablesudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `6.0 (Beta):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-nextsudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `7.0 (Aurora): sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurorasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `8.0 (Nightly):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get install firefox-trunk`
>
> `Thunderbird`
>
> `5.0 (Stable):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stablesudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `6.0 (Beta):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-nextsudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `7.0 (Aurora):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/thunderbird-aurorasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
>
> `8.0 (Nightly):sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get install thunderbird-trunk`